# How to get a specfic children with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

When I click "add2" button, I want to get the value of class "num". I try to use jquery .children() but failed.

HTML segment:(BTW: there are several similar segments in my html)

```
<ul class="price-num">
    <li>￥<a class="colorred unit_price" >10.00</a>/kg</li>
    <li class="addimg fr">
        <input class="add2" name="" type="button">
    </li>
    <li class="countbtn" style="display:none" data-level-id="3">
        <input type="button" name="" class="reduce">
        <input type="text" name="" class="num" value="0" data-prodcut-id="3">
        <input class="add" name="" type="button">
    </li>
    <li><font color="#808080" size="2px"><s> ￥12.00&nbsp;&nbsp;</s></font></li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
var quantity_item = $(this).parent().next().children('input.num')
console.log($(quantity_item[0]).val())
```

I always get "underfined" in the console. How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/68pLyp8e/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : use `closest` to get the parent `ul` and then use `.find()` to get input with `class="num"`

```
var quantity_item = $(this).closest('.price-num').find('input.num:first');
console.log($(quantity_item).val());
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sf7uvnv6/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

this will work fine:

```
console.info(quantity_item.val())
```

===

and if only one `.num` class in `ul.price-num`,I suggest u use this:

```
$(".add2").click(function(){
    var num = $("ul.price-num .num");
    console.info(num.val());
})
```

but if you there are many `.num` class **and `.num` alway in the next li after `li .add2`**,you should use this version:

```
$(".add2").click(function(){
    var num = $(this).parents("li").next().find(".num");
    console.info(num.val());
})
```